# how to add link on wordpress wonder plugin carousel description

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

i am try to set link on description using wonder plugin carousel in wordpress.
here i am type in description something like 
`<a href="test.com">test</a>`
its display in front side simple text and when i edit this again then its show in description textarea 
 `test</a>`
 here is  i have one demo output what i expect [image]

any suggestion?

thanks.

Comment: is that the option to link the image??

Comment: @AnjuRaghunath no its simple i wrote &lt;a&gt;here Link&lt;/a&gt;

Comment: @AnjuRaghunath but this link to image i want to description link

Comment: by default it is not possible.please ask the question in the plugin home page.